# Square of the Absolute Value of a Characteristic Function is a Characteristic Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I am working on the following problem:

> Suppose that $\varphi(t)$ is the characteristic function for some random variable.
>
> Show that $|\varphi(t)|^2$ is a characteristic function. For what random variable?

So I know that $\varphi(t)=E\left(e^{itX}\right)$

Also I get that $|\varphi(t)|^2=\varphi(t) \overline{\varphi(t)}=E\left(e^{itX}\right)\overline{E\left(e^{itX}\right)}=E\left(e^{itX}\right)E\left(e^{-itX}\right).$

Here I get stuck trying to continue the calculation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then: $$\phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)$$

If $Y$ and $-X$ have the same distribution then: $$\phi_Y(t)=\overline{\phi_X(t)}$$

Comment: Can we always assume the existence of an independent copy of a random variable $X$ on the same space? It seems to me that we may have to "double" the given probability space by forming the product.

Comment: @NiU What you ask in your comment is a question on its own (and the answer is: no). Fortunately it is no obstacle here, where we are actually dealing with distributions (not random variables).  For every CDF $F$ we can build a suitable probability space such that two iid random variables $X,Y$ exist on it with $F_X=F=F_Y$. This indeed by forming a product, as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Let $X'$ be an independent copy of $X$, then $\exp(itX)$ and $\exp(-itX')$ are independent also, but, as $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution, we have $\overline{\phi(t)} = \mathbf E[\exp(-itX')]$. Now use what you know about the expectation of independent products.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another look at this using Fourier analysis. If $X$ has cdf $F(x) = \mathbb P(X \leqslant x)$, then $-X$ has cdf $G(x) = 1-F(-x)$. Since a probability measure is determined by its cdf, and by the way that the Fourier transform interacts with convolution,
$$
\widehat{F\ast G} = \hat F\cdot \hat G = \mathbb E(e^{itX})\cdot \mathbb E(e^{-itX}) = |\varphi(t)|^2.
$$
So take a r.v. distributed according to $F\ast G$, say $X - Y$, where $X,Y\sim F$ are independent.